# Can I revert to a normal Google broswer instead of the streamlined 'Ubuntu Start Page'

Tags: firefox

When I open FireFox browser in Ubuntu, I am presented with a streamlined Google search interface . Oftentimes, I am looking for images, so i have to 'Google' Google, in order to get the the main Google search site ( which has links to 'images - maps - youtube - etc... in the header ). It's not a huge problem, but when searching for images for clients dozens of times a day it gets a bit frustrating having that extra step. Does anyone know how to display your home page in FireFox as the default Google Page, as opposed to the streamlined Ubuntu Version? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to go to **edit** -> **preferences**

On the general tab set the **start page** to http://www.google.com

Comment: Or this page https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=xx-hacker

Comment: matteosister, such a simple fix. Thanks for the help!